Sharing auth session between SPA and Chrome extension
I have a React application and a Chrome extension. Authentication is currently implemented within the SPA. Now, I want to extend this authentication functionality to my Chrome extension seamlessly, without requiring users to manually log in to the extension. Is there a correct way to do this without the use of cookies?
Would I need to send my Bearer token to the Chrome extension through messages? -
Here is a sample code -
function Callback() {
  const { accessToken, setAccessToken } = useAuth();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [searchParams, _] = useSearchParams();

  const sendTokenToExtension = (access_token: string) => {
    const extensionId = "";
    // chrome.runtime.connect(extensionId, { name: "example" });
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, access_token); <----- This does not work, Chrome is not defined error
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/github/callback`,
          {
            params: {
              state: searchParams.get("state"),
              code: searchParams.get("code"),
              scope: searchParams.get("scope"),
              prompt: "consent",
            },
          }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
          setAccessToken(response.data.access_token);
          sendTokenToExtension(response.data.access_token);
          navigate("/dashboard");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return <>Redirecting now..</>;
}

export default Callback;

The code below is where I would set the accessToken to my secure local storage -
background.ts
console.log("Starting auth-listener..")

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Received message from " + sender + ": ", request)
    sendResponse({ received: true }) //respond however you like
  }
)

Will sending the accessToken via messages be a security risk? is there a better way to do this?

To send to an extension from the web page you need to define externally_connectable in manifest.json.

@wOxxOm Thanks for the message, I already have this in my manifest, when I attempt to login I face the error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage') is there a way I can resolve this?

It means you've used/declared it incorrectly or you didn't reload the extension and the tab.
